# vb.net global image filepath

Tags: vb.net

Im trying to add pictures to an excel file, in this excel file command it asks for a image Path not the image...

i have added images to my resources but can't programatically find there path ( say it was installed on another machine )

anyone know how that would look ?

```
 filepath of my.Resources.zoo_picture_1 . tostring??
```

any help is appreciated

ok i disagree with the downvote ... i just need to konw how to find out the imagepath of the my.resouces.zoo_picture_1 picture..... there not going to always be located on my c: drive...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since embedded resources are not part of the file system hierarchy, there's no way to get a path to them. You'll need to distribute your images as files alongside your application.